# Running Fitness on Netgear NAS storage but it grinds to a halt after some time

Tags: fitnesse

I am using Fitnesse as a home Wiki and running it on a Netgear NAS storage solution. The OS distribution is Linux Axentra. I'm not expecting performance to be great but there are only 2 people using Fitnesse on a casual basis and thinking I can get away with it on this under specced hardware.

I'm finding that the Netgear Stora is grinding to a halt especially when I am using Fitnesse. The only way to fix this is to remove the power and restart. Can anyone suggest where I might start looking for a solution. I have spent some time on Google and wondering if this has something to do with memory.

I'm not strong technically (it took me a fair bit of time just to get Fitnesse installed and starting) however, I'm keen and willing to try things out if I can get a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: My guess would be not enough memory?  What processor and memory does the NAS have?

Comment: I was looking at Netgear's site.  These devices run on ARM processors with 512MB of RAM.  I'm guessing that while it may be possible to run just the wiki, forking to run tests is just going to be too much for that unit.  We do run into memory issues when parsing big tables.  Not an issue on a less constrained environment.